# ADInterstitialAd doesn't work on ipad swift

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, swift, iad

I implemented an ADInterstitialAd and it works fine on iphones but it doesn't work on ipad. Here is my code:

```
   func close(sender: UIButton) {

    closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
    interAdView.removeFromSuperview()
}

func loadAd() {
    println("load ad")
    interAd = ADInterstitialAd()
    interAd.delegate = self
}

func interstitialAdDidLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
    println("ad did load")

    interAdView = UIView()

    interAdView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
    self.view?.addSubview(interAdView)

    interAd.presentInView(interAdView)
    UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()

    interAdView.addSubview(closeButton)
}

func interstitialAdDidUnload(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
    closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
    interAdView.removeFromSuperview()
}

func interstitialAd(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("failed to receive")
    println(error.localizedDescription)


    closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
    interAdView.removeFromSuperview()

}
```

it prints 'ad did load' but on ipad it only shows the closebutton and not the adview and it doesn't print a error description. I imported the iAd framework and included the ADInterstitialAdDelegate in my class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `presentInView` method will return a boolean to tell you if it presented ok.  So I would start by checking that.

If that returns `NO` then check that the view you are presenting the ad into is actually the size you expect it to be.  The ad won't present if the view isn't big enough.  You may be presenting the ad too early in the view lifecycle and the view hasn't been sized to fit the screen yet?

Some other notes:

You don't need the `UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()` call because that method isn't for people using `ADInterstitialAd` directly.  You prepare Ads just but creating an instance of `ADInterstitialAd`.

The `ADInterstitialAd` object is a single use object so make sure you get a fresh one each time.

Also `UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()` is part of an simpler api where you don't have to manage `ADInterstitialAd` yourself.  If you don't have any special requirements you may prefer to use that api.

Comment: Thanks! And how can I get the right size? Now I use the whole screen as the adview. Or is the ipad ADInterstitialAd view too big? I can't make it bigger.

Comment: Ok so did you check the return from present in view? Did it return NO? Did you check the size of the view you are presenting into? What size is it? It needs to be about the size of the screen, they allow you a bit of room for toolbars etc.  How you get the view the right size is another topic, either timing, you'll need to look into the view controller life cycle, and / or auto layout etc

Comment: It returns NO and the view has the same size as the display.

Comment: As far as I know the only reasons a loaded ad won't show is because it thinks the view is too small or not actually on screen etc.  I think this is to stop fraud so you can't pretend you are showing ads but not have them actually appear on screen.  So double check every thing, the size of the view, give the view a background color so you can see it, make sure it is actually on screen when the call to present ad is made.  You could try adding a button to make sure it's not a timing issue, wait until the screen is fully visible then press the button to present the ad (just to test of course)

Comment: Also your present code looks like it doesn't use the ad that's passed in to the function, the variable you use is probably the same instance, but double check that too, make sure you are presenting the instance that is actually loaded.

Comment: I found the error: when I rotate the ipad into landscape mode it shows the ad perfectly but in portrait nothing happens. Now I enabled only portrait mode in the supportedInterfaceOrientations() function but no ad appears.. How can I fix this?

Comment: Sounds like it could be a sizing / positioning issue then.  You need to debug your view layout, make sure the view is the right size and in the place you expect.  Xcode has a nice feature where you can explode your view hierarchy into a 3d view.  You pause the app in the debugger and there's a button just above the debug window.  Or you could use background colours to understand what views are where and what sizes they are, or even use image views with an image of the full screen size in place of the ad view  that you can check ends up positioned as you expect.

Comment: Yes. In the info.plist file there is an array where i can disable the landscape mode for ipad.. I only disabled it for iphone.

Comment: Ok, so that sounds like it was ultimately a positioning / layout problem then, and iAd didn't like the frame you were asking it to present into.  Once you got your layout stable, iAd was happy to present the Ad in the correctly sized and positioned frame. Good stuff.